# i'm creating alert in Oracle EBS ERP R12 i wrote this statement and i received error app-alr-01408 SQL error ora-00909 invalid number of argument

Tags: sql, erp, oracle-ebs

I'm creating alert in Oracle EBS ERP R12. I wrote this statement and I received error

> app-alr-01408 SQL error ora-00909 invalid number of argument

```sql
SELECT prla.line_num, prha.segment1,
prha.requisition_header_id, prla.requisition_line_id,prla.SUGGESTED_VENDOR_PRODUCT_CODE
INTO &pr_ln,
     &pr_num,
     &pr_hid,
     &pr_lid
FROM apps.po_requisition_headers_all prha,
     apps.po_requisition_lines_all prla
WHERE prha.requisition_header_id = 
      prla.equisition_header_id
    and nvl( prla.SUGGESTED_VENDOR_PRODUCT_CODE,0 ) not in ( SELECT NVL(pla.vendor_product_num 'x') 
FROM po_lines_all pla, po_headers_all pha
where 1 = 1 
      and pla.po_header_id = pha.po_header_id 
      and nvl(pla.CANCEL_FALG,'N') = 'N'
      and pha.type_lookup_code = 'RFQ'
      and pha.ORG_ID =prla.ORG_ID 
)
and prla.ROWID = :ROWID
```

Comment: count how many inputs there are vs expected. according to my calculation your select has 4 columns but your "into" only has 4.

Comment: thanks but i'm not getting you

Comment: also check this `pla.vendor_product_num 'x'` - do you need a comma?

Comment: thanks all for the your  contributions ,problem solved

Comment: i rectify all the errors and the oracle alert successfully parsed the SQL ,however its generating 0 records?